# Groovy @Immutable class with (im)mutable property

Tags: groovy, immutability

I'm trying to use Groovy `@groovy.transform.Immutable` to implement classes with properties of unsupported "immutable" types. In my case it is `java.io.File`

For example, having class like

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable class TwoFiles {
    File file1,file2
}
```

gives me following compile error

> Groovyc: @Immutable processor doesn't know how to handle field 'file1' of type 'java.io.File' while compiling class TwoFiles.
>       @Immutable classes only support properties with effectively immutable types including:
>       - Strings, primitive types, wrapper types, BigInteger and BigDecimal, enums
>       - other @Immutable classes and known immutables (java.awt.Color, java.net.URI)
>       - Cloneable classes, collections, maps and arrays, and other classes with special handling (java.util.Date)
>       Other restrictions apply, please see the groovydoc for @Immutable for further details

One option I found it to extend `java.io.File` to make it `Cloneable` but I'm not happy with this solution. Following code compiles and works, but having own subclass of `java.io.File` is not what I'd like.

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable class TwoCloneableFiles {
    FileCloneable file1,file2

    class FileCloneable extends File implements Cloneable{

        FileCloneable(String s) {
            super(s)
        }

        // ... and other constructors ...
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is there any other option how to use `java.io.File` *directly* in such class?

Possibly to mark `java.io.File` as "known immutable" for the purpose of `@groovy.transform.Immutable` (same as it seems to be done for `java.awt.Color`, `java.net.URI`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried using [`knownImmutableClasses`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html#knownImmutableClasses) to specify `File`?  Something like this should work:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable(knownImmutableClasses = [File])
class TwoFiles {
    File file1,file2
}
```

(With `File`, you could probably also get rougly the effect you want with the following:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class TwoFiles {
    String file1,file2
    public File getFile1() {return new File(file1)}        
    public File getFile2() {return new File(file2)}        
}

def f = new TwoFiles("/", "/Users")
assert f.file1.class == File
```

)

Comment: *knownImmutableClasses* is exactly what I need. I just have to update to Groovy 1.8.7+ ,since this parameter was introduces in this version  (up till now I was using 1.8.6 :)